# How might I break down bread into glucose in a model of the human digestive system?

Tags: human-biology, digestive-system

I need to make a model of the digestive system. It would be really nice to actually show it in action, such as by breaking down bread into glucose or something similar. Is this feasible with a small budget and non-dangerous chemicals? If so, how? This should be as similar too the real digestive system as possible.

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of the question you asked a couple days ago?  http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2385/what-is-an-simple-way-to-burn-glucose-for-visible-effect

Comment: @mikemanne: I'm asking about how to *break down* starch into glucose. Before, I was asking about how to do something with the glucose obtained from this. The answer to one is apparently Amylase, while the answer to the other is some kind of  combustion or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amylase would be worth a try. The enzyme breaks down bread (starch), and you can buy it relatively cheaply online or probably at a chemist. Amylase is secreted in your saliva and in your stomach, so it would be most realistic if it was added in your model at those two points.

Comment: Would have thought you'd need some mechanical action to break down the bread too

Comment: If you just keep some bread crust in your mouth without chewing, it does become sweet at some point. You will just be waiting for quite some time... I spent a whole school day with bread crust in my mouth XD Adding the mechanical action might be hard in a model.

Comment: @Armatus: Great. About how much time would it take, and what could I do with an glucose solution?

Comment: That depends on the concentration you use. I would aim for a ridiculously high concentration to try and get it done quickly. As for the resulting glucose-containing solution... I don't know, you could pump it out of the model stomach around the rest of the model?

Comment: I think the easier strategy would be to use saliva and coca-cola. It's a very visible process.

Comment: @bobthejoe: How would that work?

Comment: @Armatus: how much is ridiculously high?

Comment: @Armatus: I was told that amylase is only capable of starting the breakdown process, and the pancreatic and instestinal juices were responable for actually turning it into glucose. Is this true?

Comment: <en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amylase#.CE.B1-Amylase>: it breaks starch (amylose/amylopectin) into maltose and possibly glucose (amylase is the part of pancreatic juice that digests starch). I suppose you would try to dilute it as little as possible from how you buy it. I'm speculating though, I'm not sure how realistic it is to use amylase in your model.

Comment: @Armatus: Wanted to ask you for more help, but wasn't sure how to, so I'm using this. I saw that amylase came in a couple of types and required some stuff to function (at the very least, calcium). What are the types that I need, what exactly do I need for them to react properly (and in what order, etc)? Also, do you by any chance know where I might order the correct amylases so that they would arrive in time to do it before this friday (8th of june)? I live near Montreal. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: @Armatus: I was also told about [Fehling's solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fehling%27s_solution) as a way to show the broken-down glucose, but that seems hard to make. Are there any simpler methods (I heard povidone-iodine reacts to starch)? Ones that actually do something, preferably, but time is far more important than rightness.

Comment: Googling brought up this: <http://www.wineandcake.com/browse.cfm/amylase-enzyme-1.5-oz/4,7911.html> (for $2). Unfortunately I can't really help you beyond this, I haven't used amylase myself. For staining starch there's Lugol's solution but that seems to be more expensive ($20).

Comment: @Armatus: Are you certain that that is the right thing? I note at least [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Amylase) varieties thereof. Which one do I want?

Comment: Also, I just realized that I have Lugol's iodine at home as a disinfectant.

Comment: Also, that does not ship to canada, at all.

Comment: Finally, how might I arrange for these? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Amylase#Optimum_conditions_for_ptyalin

Comment: How would I calculate how much time it would take for the reaction to happen?

Comment: The pancreatic alpha amylase should be what you want. I can't really tell you anything for certain because I haven't done this myself; if you think your model is worth it you will probably just have to try (unless someone with experience in this replies). In order to reduce the pH you could try adding some weak acid like citric acid (lemon juice). It's near impossible to calculate the time accurately because you don't know your exact conditions.

Comment: @Armatus: brewers say nothing about what type of amalyse they have have, and 'pancreatic amlyase enzyme' gives me lipase and protease mixed in. Although maybe that's not so bad?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, in fact if the fat and protein content is digested as well the result might look nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking and as suggested by Rory, mechanical force probably plays a role in most instances (crustless bread may be different):

http://www.modelgut.com/dmg.html

I was hoping to post more about this but the websites of one of the institutes involved in developing the model gut doesn't provide much accessible information on first read.

Maybe this still gives you something of a starting point:

http://www.ifr.ac.uk/info/about/index.htm